# Access ograph insights from another app without admin?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, permissions, facebook-insights

Been trying to get insights data from a page in another app (without admin), yet no luck.

Been using Facebook API to access 'insights' through Open Graph.  I have two Facebook profiles:

- one being the app holder
- the other being some Facebook page not
  related to the app.

I am able to get the data when the 'app holder' has admin rights on the  'Facebook page'.
I saw Odata app and tried that, yet I wanted to keep it within the Facebook app control.
I have also linked the application with the page, hoping that will work (yet no joy).

Am I missing some 'Facebook App setting' that I can use or is this not possible?

Any thoughts much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Read the instructions on this page, it explains how to do it: [obtaining a permanent facebook oauth access token](http://liquid9.tv/blog/2011/may/12/obtaining-permanent-facebook-oauth-access-token/)

Comment: I think you should copy a brief ot the url content, in case it is broken.